# Jetpack Compose Row - Draw over child element siblings

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `LazyColumn` with `Rows` as children

I'm trying to draw a circle on just one of the row elements that overlaps the other children but the circle is being drawn below the siblings to the left and bottom

I have tried playing around with `Modifier.zIndex` with no luck.

Here's what I have:

```
@Composable
fun HorizontalGrid() {
    val days = (1..300).toList()
    val weekChunks: List<List<Int>> = days.chunked(7)
    LazyColumn {
        items(weekChunks) { days: List<Int> ->
            Week(days)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Week(days: List<Int>) {
    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        days.forEach {
            Day(it)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Day(dayOfWeek: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(48.dp)
            .padding(4.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .drawWithContent {
                    if (dayOfWeek == 17) {
                        drawContent()
                        drawCircle(Color.Gray, radius = 150F, center = Offset(50f, 50f))
                    }
                },
            text = dayOfWeek.toString()
        )
    }
}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

What I need is the circle to be over all of the squares.

Comment: On what composable did you put the z-index? Did you try it on the Box? Or did you only try it on the Text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two places where need to add `zIndex`

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun HorizontalGrid() {
    val days = (1..300).toList()
    val weekChunks: List<List<Int>> = days.chunked(7)
    LazyColumn {
        items(items = weekChunks) { days: List<Int> ->
            Week(days)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Week(days: List<Int>) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zIndex(if (days.contains(17)) 2f else 1f)
    ) {
        days.forEach {
            Day(it)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Day(dayOfWeek: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .zIndex(if (dayOfWeek == 17) 2f else 1f)
            .size(48.dp)
            .padding(4.dp)
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .drawWithContent {
                    if (dayOfWeek == 17) {
                        drawContent()
                        drawCircle(Color.Gray, radius = 150F, center = Offset(50f, 50f))
                    }
                },
            text = dayOfWeek.toString()
        )
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]